# Не работает привязка двух свойств XAML элемента к одному свойству ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, binding

## Описание проблемы

Использую контрол [MasterDetailsView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/masterdetailsview). У него есть два свойства `DetailsHeader` и `SelectedItem`. Оба привязываются к свойству `Selected` во `ViewModel`. Цель в том, чтобы в зависимости от выбранного элемента менять заголовок `DetailsHeader`. Проблема в том, что обновляется только `SelectedItem`. В `DetailsHeader` текст не появляется.

```
DetailsHeader="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Если привязать одно к другому, работает корректно - оба обновляются.

```
DetailsHeader="{x:Bind masterDetailsView.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Я не нахожу в документации ограничение на том, что свойство от контекста можно привязать только к одному свойству элемента XAML. В чем может быть проблема?

## Код

Для уведомления об изменении используется `ViewModelBase` от `MVVM Light`. Его метод `Set()` обновляется свойство и вызывает событие изменения.

```
private SampleVendorModel _selected;
public SampleVendorModel Selected 
{ 
    get => _selected;
    set => Set(ref _selected, value);
}
```

Модель выглядит так

```
public class SampleVendorModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string FullName => $"{Surname} {Name} {MiddleName}";
    public string NameWithoutSurname => $"{Name} {MiddleName}";
}
```

Контрол MasterDetailsView

```
<controls:MasterDetailsView Name="masterDetailsView"
                            MasterHeader="{x:Bind ViewModel.Title}"
                            MasterHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MasterHeaderTemplate}"  
                            DetailsHeader="{x:Bind masterDetailsView.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
                            DetailsHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DetailsHeaderTemplate}"                                   
                            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}"
                            SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
                            DetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DetailsTemplate}"                                    
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            BackButtonBehavior="Manual">
</controls:MasterDetailsView>
```

Ресурсы страницы

```
<Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 10, 0, 10" />
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MasterHeaderTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DetailsHeaderTemplate" x:DataType="viewmodels:SampleVendorModel">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FullName}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" x:DataType="viewmodels:SampleVendorModel">
            <Grid Margin="0, 10, 0, 10" RowSpacing="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{x:Bind Surname}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{x:Bind NameWithoutSurname}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DetailsTemplate"
                      x:DataType="viewmodels:SampleVendorModel">
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Surname}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MiddleName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: В `SelectedItem` поставь `Mode=TwoWay`.

Comment: @John Спасибо. Можете добавить свой ответ, отмечу решение. `SelectedItem` привязывалось только к свойству и реагировала на изменения свойства из кода. При изменении из интерфейса, `SelectedItem` не менял значение. Отсюда и отсутствие реакции у `DetailsHeader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Проблема в том, что обновляется только SelectedItem

Я ошибся. Спасибо комментарию от John. `MasterDetailsView.SelectedItem` обновляется при изменении `ViewModel.Selected` *только* из кода. В случае обновления от навигации (клик пользователя), `ViewModel.Selected` не изменяется. Потому что стоит привязка `OneWay` у `MasterDetailsView.SelectedItem`. Как следствие `MasterDetailsView.DetailsHeader` не получает уведомления об изменении.

Для такого чтобы решить проблему, нужно установить режим `TwoWay` для `MasterDetailsView.SelectedItem`.

```
DetailsHeader="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
```